# unity 5 Remove from list

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I have a problem removing an item from a generic list. Adding works correctly and I am able to add a new item to the list. However, I can't seem to remove an item.

This is my code:

```
public List<Lista> equippedItemsIDListLocal = new List<Lista>();

    [Serializable]
    public class Lista
    {
        public int playerID;
        public int itemIDD;

        public Lista(int newPlayerID ,int newItemID)
        {
            playerID = newPlayerID;
            itemIDD = newItemID;
        }

    }
```

and I add and remove with these lines:

```
equippedItemsIDListLocal.Add(new Lista(iID, itemID));

equippedItemsIDListLocal.Remove(new Lista(iID, itemID));
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **create** a new instance of a `Lista` when calling `equippedItemsIDListLocal.Remove`, thus when comparing the **instances** (not the values inside your instances), the `Remove` can't find the first `Lista` you added and doesn't remove anything.

Do this instead :

```
Lista newLista = new Lista(iID, itemID) ;

equippedItemsIDListLocal.Add( newLista );

equippedItemsIDListLocal.Remove(newLista );
```

---

The function `Remove` uses the `Object.Equals` function to compare two elements. The function compare the **references** (something similar to memory address). When you create an instance 'A', you get a reference. When creating a new instance ('B'), you get **another reference**. Thus, `Object.Equals( A, B )` returns false.

You can implement the `Equals` function of the `IEquatable<T>` generic interface if you want, and the `Remove` function will call it to compare the instances.

```
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        Lista objAsLista = obj as Lista;
        if (objAsLista == null) return false;
        else return Equals(objAsLista);
    }

    public bool Equals(Lista other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;
        return (this.playerID.Equals(other.playerID) && this.itemIDD.Equals(other.itemIDD) );
    }
```

Check the following link :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks ^^ Now I understand how it should look like !